# Running Process which take a long time

Tags: c#, process, waitforexit

I have a section in my code where I call a batch file and give it certain arguments. This batch file calls another batch file and so on. The entire process takes about 45 minutes to complete. I also need to wait for the batch file to finish before I continue with the rest of my code (cleaning up after the batch file etc).

My problem is that, although I have tried several different things, I cannot get the batch file to both complete its run as well as write its output to a log file.

Here is what I've done to get the batch file to complete its run:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
process.Start();

process.WaitForExit();
```

In an attempt to enable logging I have tried quite a few things. Here is just the latest attempt.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
process.Start();

StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput;
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(exelocation + @"Logs\" + version + "\\" + outputname + ".txt");

while (!process.HasExited)
{
      sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

This code basically makes it to a trivial part in one of the first batch files and stops there. The batch file runs for under a minute. I don't understand why this is happening. It runs perfectly if the standard output is not redirected and a window is created but does nothing if the window is hidden and the standard output redirected?

Comment: put a break point at line `sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());` and see if that line ever completes executing and go for next loop

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that the batch file is writing to the StandardError stream, and the buffer is full.

Managing the redirection of standard streams is quite tricky. You will need to read both streams asynchronously and probably merge them if you want to capture all the output. I have a class that does this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads streams from a process's <see cref="Process.StandardOutput"/> and <see cref="Process.StandardError"/>
/// streams.
/// </summary>
public class ProcessOutputReader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the combined output of StandardError and StandardOutput.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly StringBuilder combinedOutputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    /// <summary>
    /// Object that is locked to control access to <see cref="combinedOutputBuilder"/>.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly object combinedOutputLock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the error output string.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly StringBuilder errorOutputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Process"/> that this instance is reading.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Process process;

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the standard output string.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly StringBuilder standardOutputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    /// <summary>
    /// Flag to record that we are already reading asynchronously (only one form is allowed).
    /// </summary>
    private bool readingAsync;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ProcessOutputReader"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">
    /// The process.
    /// </param>
    public ProcessOutputReader(Process process)
    {
        if (process == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("process");
        }

        this.process = process;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the combined output of StandardOutput and StandardError, interleaved in the correct order.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The combined output of StandardOutput and StandardError.</value>
    public string CombinedOutput { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the error output.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The error output.
    /// </value>
    public string StandardError { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the standard output.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The standard output.
    /// </value>
    public string StandardOutput { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Begins the read process output.
    /// </summary>
    public void BeginReadProcessOutput()
    {
        if (this.readingAsync)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The process output is already being read asynchronously");
        }

        this.readingAsync = true;

        this.CheckProcessRunning();

        this.process.OutputDataReceived += this.OutputDataReceived;
        this.process.ErrorDataReceived += this.ErrorDataReceived;

        this.process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        this.process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ends asynchronous reading of process output.
    /// </summary>
    public void EndReadProcessOutput()
    {
        if (!this.process.HasExited)
        {
            this.process.CancelOutputRead();
            this.process.CancelErrorRead();
        }

        this.process.OutputDataReceived -= this.OutputDataReceived;
        this.process.ErrorDataReceived -= this.ErrorDataReceived;

        this.StandardOutput = this.standardOutputBuilder.ToString();
        this.StandardError = this.errorOutputBuilder.ToString();
        this.CombinedOutput = this.combinedOutputBuilder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the process output.
    /// </summary>
    public void ReadProcessOutput()
    {
        if (this.readingAsync)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The process output is already being read asynchronously");
        }

        this.BeginReadProcessOutput();
        this.process.WaitForExit();
        this.EndReadProcessOutput();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Appends a line of output to the specified builder and to the combined output.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The target builder.</param>
    /// <param name="line">The line of output.</param>
    private void AppendLine(StringBuilder builder, string line)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(line);
        lock (this.combinedOutputLock)
        {
            this.combinedOutputBuilder.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks that the process is running.
    /// </summary>
    private void CheckProcessRunning()
    {
        // process.Handle will itself throw an InvalidOperationException if the process hasn't been started.
        if (this.process.HasExited)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Process has exited");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the ErrorDataReceived event on the monitored process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            this.AppendLine(this.errorOutputBuilder, e.Data);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the OutputDataReceived event on the monitored process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            this.AppendLine(this.standardOutputBuilder, e.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```
var batchFile = Path.Combine(this.TestContext.TestSupportFileDir, "WriteToStandardError.bat");
var process = StartProcess(batchFile);
var reader = new ProcessOutputReader(process);
reader.ReadProcessOutput();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to pick up the output at the end (i.e. you don't need to display it as the process runs), simply use CMD.EXE to redirect it:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe /c my.bat > my.log").WaitForExit();
```